# Setting the default conda environment for Julia

Tags: anaconda, julia, conda, miniconda

I'm just starting to learn Julia in a windows platform. I've been using for quiet some time python (through miniconda and a virtual environment that I will call from now on p3). Also, I like using VSCode, so I am using the Julia 1.0.0 extension.

One of my first tasks was aimed at creating a simple plot. While I was using the Pkg, to add **Plots** and **PyPlot**, I noticed that for the latter the following command was issued: `conda install matplotlib`.

Because I use Miniconda (that is the base environment), I initially suspected that the (base) environment was called. However upon closer inspection I realised that in my user folder there was a `.julia/conda` folder that contained the data.

So my questions are:

- does julia use and maintain a separate conda environment in order to communicate with python?
- Is it possible to move the .julia folder (or more specifically the conda folder which tends to get a bit bulky to another directory).
- Is it possible to create different conda environments for use within julia?

If my questions are too naive/answered elsewhere, then I would appreciate it if you could just point me to the relative documentation/tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand, [PyPlot.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl) relies on [PyCall.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) to run python code. In turn PyCall relies on [Conda.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/Conda.jl) to manage the python environment.

While Conda.jl allows you to manage several environments, it looks like only the "root" environment will be used by PyCall. The [Conda.jl documentation](https://github.com/JuliaPy/Conda.jl#using-a-pre-existing-conda-installation) gives a few pointers on how to change the location of this root environment.

So, to answer your questions:

> does julia use and maintain a separate conda environment in order to communicate with python?

By default, yes

> Is it possible to move the .julia folder (or more specifically the conda folder which tends to get a bit bulky to another directory).

It is possible to move the entire .julia folder by setting the [JULIA_DEPOT_PATH](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/#JULIA_DEPOT_PATH-1) environment variable. Or to move only the conda root environment by setting the `CONDA_JL_HOME` env var and rebuilding Conda.jl as explained in the link above.

> Is it possible to create different conda environments for use within julia?

Not sure I understand your question. If you mean to ask whether there can be multiple possible conda environments and you'd choose which one to use for a particular Julia session, then AFAIU no: everything relying on PyCall will ever use the "root" conda environment.

Answer (score 5):

By default Julia is using the inbuilt Anaconda, however you can use any other Python installation. You can change the Python environment that is used with Julia by pointing to a different Python executeable:

```
ENV["PYTHON"]="C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"
using Pkg
pkg"build PyCall"
```

Note that after changing the environment `PyCall` needs to be rebuilt.
You can manage your packages either via `Conda.jl` or `conda` command that comes with Python installation or even `pip`. Julia should work with any Python installation, however with the Anaconda or Miniconda distribution you will have the best experience.

I recommend also reading `PyCall` [installation instructions](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#installation)

Finally, if you are not happy with your new Python configuration the above can be reverted to the inbuilt Python via:

```
ENV["PYTHON"]=""
pkg"build PyCall"
```